# Not sure if this is a problem with android studio or flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I downloaded flutter for android studio and after I started getting this error while trying to run myapp on a virtual device. Before I was using Kotlin for android studio and everything would run fine. I have tried deleting and redownloading both flutter and Android studio.

[This is the Error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxXdT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Which Flutter version are you using? And what android version are you using for the emulator?

Comment: For android studio I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 

For Flutter I am using Flutter 2.2.3 and Dart 2.13.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you don`t have accept android license accept it and run below command on your terminal hope it help you

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and accept the android license

if problem is not solved change the  **compileSdkVersion 29 , minSdkVersion 23,
targetSdkVersion 29**  in build.gradle file here `android/app/build.gradle`
and relaunch your app

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get home from work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Change the JDK Version

> **j.d.k 16.0.2**  to  **j.d.k 15.0**