# There is a error in android studio but same code working on flutlab.io

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried to run a basic code in android studio. but it showing error. but the same code successfully compiled on flutlab.io

here is the error message.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\helloapp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i'm new to android studio. so please tell what's the wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240279/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file)

Comment: try to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640043/13997210

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JAVA SDK 15.

First remove your old JDK, and download & install Java JDK 15 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk15-archive-downloads.html).

Then, in Android Studio, change the path to the Java JDK so that it matches the latest install. Finally, restart Android Studio to apply the changes.

Comment: yes. i tried to install with watching a you Tube video. but that is JAVA but i want flutter.  already downloaded  JAVA SDK also. what's the problem here?

Comment: it's JDK version issue .you can remove old JDK version and download JDK 15 from here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk15-archive-downloads.html.  after set new path it is JDK 15 than restart Android studio

Comment: Thank You. i downloaded sdk 15 and now it working