# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could not find method lintOptions() for arguments in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

'When I am running my flutter project it is showing me below error. I have tried many things but it is not resolving. Please help me to resolve this issue'

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\IT-2\Desktop\AI-Radio-main\android\app\build.gradle' line: 47

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method lintOptions() for arguments [build_bbpz8d3vjjv1wtg6vsdz8r5bn$_run_closure5@219834fd] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 939ms
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                      1,727ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

' Here is my app/build.gradle'

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
         // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
         quiet true
         // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
         abortOnError false
         // set to true to have all release builds run lint on issues with severity=fatal
         // and abort the build (controlled by abortOnError above) if fatal issues are found
         checkReleaseBuilds true
         // if true, only report errors
         ignoreWarnings true
         // if true, emit full/absolute paths to files with errors (true by default)
         //absolutePaths true
         // if true, check all issues, including those that are off by default
         checkAllWarnings true
         // if true, treat all warnings as errors
         warningsAsErrors true
         // turn off checking the given issue id's
         disable 'TypographyFractions','TypographyQuotes'
         // turn on the given issue id's
         enable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'
         // check *only* the given issue id's
         check 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'
         // if true, don't include source code lines in the error output
         noLines true
         // if true, show all locations for an error, do not truncate lists, etc.
         showAll true
         // whether lint should include full issue explanations in the text error output
         explainIssues false
         // Fallback lint configuration (default severities, etc.)
         lintConfig file("default-lint.xml")
         // if true, generate a text report of issues (false by default)
         textReport true
         // location to write the output; can be a file or 'stdout' or 'stderr'
         //textOutput 'stdout'
         textOutput file("lint-results.txt")
         // if true, generate an XML report for use by for example Jenkins
         xmlReport true
         // file to write report to (if not specified, defaults to lint-results.xml)
         xmlOutput file("lint-report.xml")
         // if true, generate an HTML report (with issue explanations, sourcecode, etc)
         htmlReport true
         // optional path to report (default will be lint-results.html in the builddir)
         htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")
         // Set the severity of the given issues to fatal (which means they will be
         // checked during release builds (even if the lint target is not included)
         fatal 'NewApi', 'InlineApi'
         // Set the severity of the given issues to error
         error 'Wakelock', 'TextViewEdits'
         // Set the severity of the given issues to warning
         warning 'ResourceAsColor'
         // Set the severity of the given issues to ignore (same as disabling the check)
         ignore 'TypographyQuotes'
         // Set the severity of the given issues to informational
         informational 'StopShip'
         // Use (or create) a baseline file for issues that should not be reported
         baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
         // Normally most lint checks are not run on test sources (except the checks
         // dedicated to looking for mistakes in unit or instrumentation tests, unless
         // ignoreTestSources is true). You can turn on normal lint checking in all
         // sources with the following flag, false by default:
         checkTestSources true
         // Like checkTestSources, but always skips analyzing tests -- meaning that it
         // also ignores checks that have explicitly asked to look at test sources, such
         // as the unused resource check.
         ignoreTestSources true
         // Normally lint will skip generated sources, but you can turn it on with this flag
         checkGeneratedSources true
         // Normally lint will analyze all dependencies along with each module; this ensures
         // that lint can correctly (for example) determine if a resource declared in a library
         // is unused; checking only the library in isolation would not be able to identify this
         // problem. However, this leads to quite a bit of extra computation; a library is
         // analyzed repeatedly, for each module that it is used in.
         checkDependencies false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ai_radio"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }


flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Try to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640043/13997210 hope it helps.

Comment: Already tried @RavindraS.Patil